# PHP - Access array in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with response from Youtube Data API and I don't know how to read each values in the array.

```
Array
(
[0] => youtube#channelListResponse
[1] => "X"
   [2] => Array (
                 [totalResults] => 1
                 [resultsPerPage] => 1
                )
[3] => Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
          [kind] => youtube#channel
          [etag] => "XX"
          [id] => XXX
            )
        )
)
```

When I try to access `[id]` with `echo $array[3]['id']` it returns `Notice: Undefined offset: 3`

Comment: You mean how to access single values or loop through each value?

Comment: what you want as an output?

Comment: To access `totalResults` for an example, you would do: `echo $arrayname[2]['totalResults']`.

Comment: It returns: `Notice: Undefined offset: 2`

Comment: @khalnas Are you certain your array looks like this? Could you give us the exact output from `print_r` (without ruining the formatting)?

Comment: `Array
(
[kind] => youtube#channelListResponse
[etag] => "X"
[pageInfo] => Array
(
[totalResults] => 1
[resultsPerPage] => 1
)
[items] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[kind] => youtube#channel
[etag] => "XX"
[id] => X
)
)
)`

Comment: So as you can see it's `$array['pageInfo']['totalResults']`

Answer (score 0):

AS Max said you can access single value in array in array by

```
$arrayName[index]['key']
```

Example You can access 'kind' with

```
$arrayName[3]['kind']
```

Since, inner level array is key value paired you need to specify key instead of index.
If you want to access all value, you can do it with foreach loop and check type of each value use'gettype()' method. if type is array then use same function recursively.

Comment: It returns: `Undefined offset: 3`